# How many permissions can be created in an EOS account?

Tags: blockchain, eos

Is there any limit in the number of custom permissions that can be created in the same EOS account?

Answer (score 0):

The updated documentation has some new details about permissions.

Here is a page that might be related to what you are asking about:
https://developers.eos.io/welcome/latest/protocol/accounts_and_permissions

Otherwise, I don't know the cap to the number of permissions an account could have.